# Pass column name as parameter for MySql function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write MySql function were I pass  table name used in a select statement this is a toy code explaining the issue I am facing.[Note : I don't want to use procedures !]

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `P_AVG`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION P_AVG(tblName CHAR(64)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
    DECLARE cnt INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM tblName;
return cnt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then I try to execute the following

```
SELECT P_AVG("PARTSUPP");
```

I get the following error

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'phpmyadmin.tblName' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

To select the table at runtime - you need to use prepared statements - create the SQL as a string with the required table name. See third example : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable to compose your SQL query dynamically and then let MySQL prepare a statement out of the composed SQL query string and execute it dynamically, in the form of a prepared statement.

As dynamic SQL is not allowed inside a Stored Function, you need to go for a STORED PROCEDURE.

This should do it for you:-

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `P_AVG`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE P_AVG(tblName CHAR(64))
BEGIN   
  DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    IF CHAR_LENGTH(tblName) > 0 THEN 
       SET @DYNAMIC_QUERY = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM ', tblName);
       PREPARE STMNT FROM @DYNAMIC_QUERY;
       EXECUTE STMNT;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMNT;
    END IF;
  SELECT cnt; /* The return statement becomes a regular `SELECT` statement, 
                 although an OUT parameter also can be used instead. */
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL P_AVG('ACCOUNT'); -- Example procedure call
```

Comment: it generate the following error ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DYNAMIC_QUERY;

Comment: o.O another : ERROR 1336 (0A000): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: Then you need to write it as a stored procedure instead. A `PROCEDURE` instead of `FUNCTION`.